# How to change BIG dataframe format: patients with 2 visits and multiple variables for each visit

Tags: r, dataframe, format, rstudio

I have a large dataframe (15000 observations of 800 variables). The observations are patients at 2 different time points (i.e. 15000 obs = 10000 patients at baseline visit + 5000 of the first 10000 who came back for a follow-up visit). Patients have a patientID variable (PtID: factor with 10000 levels) and a visit variable (Visit: factor with 2 levels: 1 for baseline, 2 for follow-up).

Example of data

```
    PtID Visit Age_Visit Brain_colour    BP       .................
     40    1        60         NA        130 
     40    2        62         blue      120
     70    1        50         green     145
     101   1        67         red       67
     263   1        78         red       178
     263   2        80         green     90
     143   1        15         blue      123
     219   1        69         red       110
     219   2        70         green     NA
```

I would like to change the format of the dataframe so each patient is one single observation with the 800 baseline variables repeated as a different follow-up variable (going from a 15000 obs of 800 variables to a 10000 obs (baseline patients only) of 1600 variables). The 5000 patients with no follow-up will have NA values for all the follow-up variables.

I found the below code from another question BUT having so many variables that I need to change I cannot list them all.

```
 d <- setDT(x)[, list(WorryHighBGNow = paste(WorryHighBGNow, 
 collapse = ', ')),by = c('PtID')]
```

In addition I would like to create the new follow-up variables. How can I easily change my above data to the below data for such a large dataframe?

```
     PtID Age_Visit1 Age_Visit2 Brain_colour1 Brain_colour2  BP1       BP2       .................
     40      60       62          NA          blue           120       145 
     70      50       NA          green        NA            145       NA
     101     67       NA          red          NA             67       NA
     263     78       80          red         green          178       90
     ...................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  gather(col, val, -c(PtID, Visit)) %>%
  unite("col2", c("col", "Visit")) %>%
  spread(col2, val)

  PtID Age_Visit_1 Age_Visit_2 BP_1 BP_2 Brain_colour_1 Brain_colour_2
1   40          60          62  130  120           <NA>           blue
2   70          50        <NA>  145 <NA>          green           <NA>
3  101          67        <NA>   67 <NA>            red           <NA>
4  143          15        <NA>  123 <NA>           blue           <NA>
5  219          69          70  110 <NA>            red          green
6  263          78          80  178   90            red          green
```

---

Edit:
To preserve the variable types, one approach would be to perform the same task separately for all the character columns, all the numeric columns, etc., and then bind them together.

```
# First collect list of all the numeric and character columns
df_num_cols <- df %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names()
df_char_cols <- df %>% select_if(is.character) %>% names()

df_nums <- df %>%
  select_at(vars(c("PtID", Visit, df_num_cols))) %>%
  gather(col, val, -c(PtID, Visit)) %>%
  unite("col2", c("col", "Visit")) %>%
  spread(col2, val)

df_chars <- df %>%
  select_at(vars(c("PtID", Visit, df_char_cols))) %>%
  gather(col, val, -c(PtID, Visit)) %>%
  unite("col2", c("col", "Visit")) %>%
  spread(col2, val)

df2 <- bind_cols(df_nums, df_chars)
df2 %>% str()

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ PtID          : int  40 70 101 143 219 263
 $ Age_Visit_1   : int  60 50 67 15 69 78
 $ Age_Visit_2   : int  62 NA NA NA 70 80
 $ BP_1          : int  130 145 67 123 110 178
 $ BP_2          : int  120 NA NA NA NA 90
 $ PtID1         : int  40 70 101 143 219 263
 $ Brain_colour_1: chr  NA "green" "red" "blue" ...
 $ Brain_colour_2: chr  "blue" NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: This however has changed all my variables (integer, factor, numeric) to characters. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, but I think it'll add a few steps to keep the same structure. I'll take a look. There might also be a more elegant data.table approach, or you could use the development version of `tidyr`, which has a more powerful spread/gather idiom, pivot_wider/pivot_longer.

Comment: I've found a way to preserve the numeric class but for some reason factors are still converted into characters, posting it below your edit (by the way thanks Jon you are great!)

Answer (score 0):

Changing Dataframe from LONG to WIDE (this will preserve the NUMERIC class but will still auto-convert all FACTORS to CHARACTERS):

```
         library(tidyr)                              
         df_wide <- df_long %>%
         gather(col, val, -c(PtID, Visit)) %>%
         unite("col2", c("col", "Visit")) %>%
         spread(col2, val, convert = TRUE)
```

Converting CHARACTERS back to FACTORS:

```
         df_wide <- as.data.frame(unclass(df_wide))
```